# Host dart app in home hosting

Tags: dart, hosting

I have a hosting in my home where I'm hosting my website,
Can I host my dart application there?
Do I have to install anything?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To host a dart application, the only thing you need is the dart-sdk available [here](https://www.dartlang.org/)

After you write your dart application, run it like :

> *link_to_your_dart_dir*/dart-sdk/bin/dart your_main.dart

Be careful to have run

> pub get

in the same directory than your pubspec.yaml.

it's pretty the same than with python or ruby.

Answer (score 0):

I use https://drone.io to automatically build from git hub via `pub build`. Then I setup drone to have a server deploy that scps/rsync the 'build/web' directory to my deployment server.

You can do this all locally if you want with the dart sdk also. I find drone nice because it's all hooked into git hub and makes a build for every push so I know which changesets pass and which fail.